#  'selCurrentManuf' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

i have a drop down list i am trying to use the id of in a sql in the code behind but i get error...

is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

```
  <asp:DropDownList  
  selectedvalue='<%#Container.DataItem("manufidcurrent")%>' 
  ID="selCurrentManuf" 
  Runat="Server" 
  DataTextField="Desc" 
  DataValueField="manufid"
  DataSource="<%# GetCurrentManuf() %>" 
  autopostback="true" 
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="selCurrentManuf_SelectedIndexChanged"  ></asp:DropDownList>
```

In the code behind i have a function trying to use the selected option...

```
Function GetCurrentModel() As DataSet
Dim mySession = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session
Dim myQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM model where id = " + selCurrentManuf.SelectedItem.Value
Dim myConnection As New MySqlConnection(mySession("localConn"))
myConnection.Open()
Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand(myQuery, myConnection)
Dim myDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
Dim myDataset As New DataSet
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataset, "model")
Dim dr As DataRow = myDataset.Tables(0).NewRow       
myDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dr)      
GetCurrentModel =  myDataset             
End Function
```

Comment: ***What*** is not declared...?

Comment: This is ripe for SQL Injection, you should consider using a parameterized query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dropdownlist is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678387/dropdownlist-is-not-declared-it-may-be-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the `designer.cs` file gets screwed up. You can add the DropDown to the `designer.cs` file manually, or cutting and pasting the dropdown into the markup again may correct the problem.

To declare the DropDown manually in the `designer.cs` file:

```
/// <summary>
/// selCurrentManuf control.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Auto-generated field.
/// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
/// </remarks>
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList selCurrentManuf;
```

Comment: where would this file b?

Comment: Go to the solution explorer and expand the ASPX file.

Comment: this app is running on web server i dont have it in vs

Comment: So you're developing an application with no IDE? I'd like to know how to do that.

Comment: nope no ide, was created in one uploaded to server and now jsut have access to the aspx and aspx.vb files not the project

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: 2.0 i think im just missing something obvious

Comment: i have the exact same code working on another page except the dropdown list created filled with a function