# dropdownlist is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

As you can see from the commented out code, I'm trying to get the model dropdown be affected by `+ selCurrentManuf.Text`.

I get this error

> 'selCurrentManuf' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

How can this be solved?

I can access the drop down in another part of the page like this..

```
Dim sc1_currentmanuf As String = CType(e.Item.FindControl("selCurrentManuf"), DropDownList).Text
```

However in the function i am trying to use selCurrentManuf does not have access to e

Comment: you might want to check the access modifier, right click on the dropdown element and check for properties.

Comment: sorry i cant get it into vs i only cant edit in notepad ++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Dim sc1_currentmanuf As String = CType(dlContacts.Items(0).FindControl("selCurrentManuf"), DropDownList).Text
    Dim myQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM c5_model where c5_manufid = " + sc1_currentmanuf
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your .aspx page, and select the command Convert To Web Application.

Then you'll be able to write:

```
  Dim myQuery As String = 
    String.Format("SELECT * FROM c5_model WHERE c5_manuf = '{0}'", 
                  selCurrentManuf.SelectedItem.Text )
```

Comment: i dont have the project in VS, its been put upto webserver and i can only manually edit the aspx and aspx.vb pages

Comment: also when i tried that i still got error... 'selCurrentManuf' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Get it into Visual Studio; make a new solution. You're going to want to edit this project in Visual Studio at some point; no better time than now (when it's broken).

Comment: Right click on your .aspx page, and select the command Convert To Web Application.
that really worked wonder just because of the designer file malfunction ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your functions are inside a class in your App_Code or another dll and not on the code behind of the page.

If so do this instead:

I'm assuming you have something like this on your asp page code behind:

```
Protected Sub selCurrentManuf_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        GetCurrentModel(selCurrentManuf.Text)
End Sub
```

Change Your GetCurrentModel Code To:

```
Function GetCurrentModel(Byval c5_manuf as String) As DataSet
    Dim mySession = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session
    Dim myQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM c5_model " 'where c5_manuf = " + + c5_manuf 
    Dim myConnection As New MySqlConnection(mySession("localConn"))
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand(myQuery, myConnection)
    Dim myDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
    Dim myDataset As New DataSet
    myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataset, "c5_model")
    Dim dr As DataRow = myDataset.Tables(0).NewRow       
    myDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dr)      
    GetCurrentModel =  myDataset
    myConnection.Close()         
 End Function
```

Comment: still get 'selCurrentManuf' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Try checking if your ASPX File is correctly Inheriting Your Page File Class

Comment: how do i do this? everything works fine if i dont try access the selCurrentManu in the code behind

Comment: i have expanded the view it may have something to do with the drop down being in datalist thing?